# How to replace String by Using JScript in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I try to replace the word "PROCENT" to "%" in an ASP file.
But I got error:

```
Error "800a01b6'  
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

```
<%@ language="javascript"%>
<%
var newSpanPosBeschreibung = Request.QueryString("newSpan");
if(newSpanPosBeschreibung.indexOf("PROCENT") >= 0 ){
    newSpanPosBeschreibung = newSpanPosBeschreibung.replace(/PROCENT/g, "%");
}
//then save the [newSpanPosBeschreibung] into Databank.
%>
```

How to replace the "PROCENT" to "%"? Thx!

Comment: @dfsq It's a String. var newSpanPosBeschreibung = Request.QueryString("newSpanPosBeschreibung");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if you cast the variable to a string first?

```
var newSpanPosBeschreibung = String(Request.QueryString("newSpan"));
```

Comment: var newSpanPosBeschreibung = (string)Request.QueryString("newSpan");       There is an another error"800a03ec'   need ';'

Comment: The correct way to cast is to use the `String()` function. It should work now.

Comment: @YingStyle - if that solved your problem are you going to mark it as the correct answer